# Disable Network Time synchronization in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line

How to enable network time synchronization on Ubuntu 16.04?
How to verify/ensure that network time synchronization is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I have 'ntpd' running and in Time/Date settings synchronization is enabled:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ntp
ntp       1643     1  0 11:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 121:129
```

[image]

If you DON'T want this enabled, set the Configuration to manual and remove the ntpd package from your system.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether time synchronization works type

```
ntpstat
```

in command prompt. It should write how accurate your clock is if it is synchronized. To check how it is synchronized in more detail try this

```
ntpq -c pe
```

or longer

```
ntpq -c peers
```

To see if ntp service works type

```
systemctl status ntp.service
```

You can stop it with

```
systemctl stop ntp.service
```

and start it with

```
systemctl start ntp.service
```

You can see some settings for Time & Date in System Settings. As seen in the picture, you can switch off Automatic Date & Time. This will stop your time synchronization.

[image]

And finally you have settings for time synchronization in

```
/etc/ntp.conf
```